# Pasting hindi content in WordPress but not working

Tags: wordpress, fonts, editor

We have content ready in Word file , we used Krutidev font and full content is in Hindi.

But when we are pasting that content in WordPress editor to create a page then its not appearing in hindi font. (See below screenshot)

[image]

So please suggest for this. We have approx 50 pages ready that we want to copy from word file and want to paste it in WordPress editor to create a page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to convert this text into utf-8 character.

Comment: How we can convert? I mean first we need to convert Word file text to UTF-8 and then paste? Is this you are saying ?

Comment: yes. you can try copy paste from this site. http://hindi.changathi.com/

Comment: @ManvendraRajpurohit thanks for your response. But my question was , I want to copy text from word file and want it to paste directly in WordPress editor. The site that you gave is asking to type one bye one not to paste.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Have To Try Wordpress Plugins Instead Like This-http://www.vishalon.net/pramukhime/wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Hosting Control Panel
Check the directory where the WordPress is installed (Root Directory or Sub Directory or Sub Domain) and find Wp-Config.php file.
Search for the comments:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */

define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8’);

/** The Database Collate type. Don’t change this if in doubt. */

define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

and just add // slash before the main comments like this:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */

//define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8’);

/** The Database Collate type. Don’t change this if in doubt. */

//define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

Save File and close the window.